# Security Fixes in Angular

Tags: angular, security, sanitization

I'm using 3rd party tool to scan security vulnerabilities of Angular application. In that, I found few suggestions. I wanted to know is there any way / any plugins / any best-practices available to address these issues.

#### The application's embeds untrusted data in the generated output with location (Client DOM XSS)

This suggestion is more about two-way bindings. Here, **location.name** is assigned to **ngModel**.

```
<input id="input" class="e-input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="location.name" required />
```

Another example is assigning data-source to custom controls.

```
<Mydropdownlist id='ddlLocationHierarchy' [dataSource]="hierarchyLevel" ....
```

And even adding object to array :

```
this.myArray.push(Object.assign({}, this.location));
```

#### The application's load embeds untrusted data in the generated output with bind (Client DOM Stored Code Injection)

Here, accessing session Storage Item by Key.

```
headerName = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.LOGIN_ID);
```

And some are with dynamic string building inside HTML

```
Answer {{ screenType == 'reset' ? '' : '1'}}
```

Comment: Hi @Shreekumar S, Please have a look [DOM Sanitization](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) 
Depending on your requirement if you are getting the data from the service you can use ```bypassSecurityTrustScript``` if you are getting the HTML in response you can use ```bypassSecurityTrustHtml ```. Please check if this suits your requirement. 
Or please share the code over ```stackblitz``` will have a look

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena `[(ngModel)]="location.name"` does angular take care of sanitization by default?